# Are there any published examples impementing the Google Latitude API for Android?

Tags: android, google-latitude

Are there any published examples impementing the Google Latitude API for Android?  I've searched, and searched down a few rabbit holes to no avail.  Has anyone successfully implemented the api in Android and willing to share some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/#svn/branches/2/sample/latitude/latitude-sample    and instructions can be found at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/branches/2/sample/latitude/latitude-sample/instructions.html  you will need to register with Google to get the authorisation key. That example is quite complex, hope it will help anyhow